# Dynamics NAV 2013 report - how do I create the equivalent of a conditional left outer join?

Tags: report, dynamics-nav

We use Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2013 R2 and I have been asked to modify a report. The report currently pulls data from the Sales Line table and I need to include the Manufacturer Part No which is stored in the Item table. The Sales Line table includes an Item No, which may or may not exist in the Item table, and the lookup should only occur where the "Type" of the Sales Line record is "Item".

If I was writing SQL, I would use a conditional left outer join for this:

```
SELECT [Other Columns], "Item"."Manufacturer Part No"
FROM "Sales Line"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Item" ON "Sales Line"."Type" = 'Item'
    AND "Sales Line"."Item No" = "Item"."No"
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh167597(v=nav.71).aspx) if I go into the report Dataset Designer, add the Item table as a data source and view the Properties, I should be able to set the DataItemLinkType to SQL Advanced Options, and the SQLJoinType to LEFT OUTER JOIN, but neither of these Properties are listed in the Properties box for the data source.

How do I access the DataItemLinkType and SQLJoinType in NAV 2013 R2, to make this a LEFT OUTER JOIN, and how do I make the join conditional on the Sales Line type being "Item"?

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible - the MSDN article whar you've linked is for Query objects.
But we need more info about this report btw to be able to help you.
Is this a standard NAV report?

Cheers

Comment: Thank-you for your reply. No, this is a custom report that was written for us.

Answer (score 0):

Like azatoth said we are going to need more information.

But from what you have written it seems like you need to add the second table as a (sub)Dataitem and use the properties to establish the link between your two tables.

The property DataItemTableView can be used to filter your sub (right) Table.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from a consultant, I have come to the conclusion that this is not directly possible in NAV, but there are two possible approaches that will give me what I want:

1. Add an additional field to the Sales Order table. Make this a Lookup field that looks up the Manufacturing Part No on the Item table, filtering using the Item No field. This approach has the advantage that the field will then be available to any page or report that uses the Sales Order table, however it does mean that those pages and reports will need a re-test to check for any unforeseen side-effects.
2. Add the Item table as a DataItem in the Report Dataset Designer, then set the PrintOnlyIfDetail property of the parent DataItem (the Sales Line DataItem) to "No". This has the effect of setting all sub-items of this parent to be LEFT OUTER joins.

Whichever approach you take, the join is not conditional, so you will need to set the visibility of the Manufacturing Part No using an Expression so it is only displayed if the Type of the Sales Line is "Item".